# Should fold AKo when 2 players already all-in?

Tags: mtt

8-handed MTT, no bubble factor yet, avg stack ~17bb:

- UTG ALL in ~20BB, TAG
- MP ALL IN 30BB, so called pro
- fold to HERO Big Blind AKo with 20BB?

What if Hero only 10BBs leave and get around 40BBs?

Comment: Not a full answer so i'll add it here: Shove/fold strategies are preferred at higher levels because they are easier to balance and harder to exploit. How wide i shove will depend on how much edge i have at the table. On a soft table there may be more +ev spots to take than call here.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a standard get in. However I think that bad players or lower stake players generally play too tight in these spots. This makes it closer but still I think it should be an all-in.

Also keep in mind UTG would probably not shove a monster hand, he would raise it. You are only worried about MP, but even against kings your aren't doing terrible. You for sure fold AQ. But AK is too good and especially a great hand to have three-ways.

Comment: There is a trend nowadays for players to shove/fold at ~15-20BB, so i wouldn't say UTG's range is capped. But still, agree with the call.

Comment: when should be right amount to shove/fold, 7 BB? or M < 3?
I have shove with 88 at UTG with 6BB, some friends said that is too loose...

Comment: It depends. With antes blind versus blind you can easily shove 25BB. This prevents you having to play out of position. On other positions I would shove 15BB maximum.

Comment: what about big blind ante? both Big blind UTG should shove on a larger range?

Answer (score 2):

Against JJ, QQ will win 36% so mathematically call.

Against AA or KK should not call.

Open for 20 BB could be a (semi) bluff. Call 20 BB is not a bluff. Would MP do that with QQ? You have blockers to AA and KK but I think you need to lay this down.

With only 10 BB I would call.

Comment: can I clarify that youre putting MP on KK+ only?

Comment: was putting UTG with Ax, middle connected suit, any pair. MP 99+ pair

Comment: @sakon Yes I am putting MP on KK+.  MP might be doing this with QQ or JJ.  It is tough call.